# Lightweight NoSQL DB Supporting REST and JSON

Tags: c++, json, rest, full-text-search, nosql

Just looking for a NoSQL DB as compact as SQLite, supporting REST and JSON, preferably implemented in C/C++ and capable of full-text search. Can you recommend it?

Comment: If you care about it being used via a RESTful interface, why do you also care what language it is written in? Just curious.

Comment: e.g. for native embeded server application.

Comment: The latest version of MongoDB 2.6 does support full text search as well..

Answer (score 5):

You may want [LevelDB](https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/), a fast key-value storage library written at Google that provides an ordered mapping from string keys to string values. You can use it as a standalone file-based database. Support for many languages (C/C++, Ruby, Java).

Also check out [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/), a lightweight database library, a straightforward implementation of DBM, Key-value store, Standalone file-based database (also in-memory)
, Support for many languages (Ruby, Java, C#, PHP, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/); it's written in C++.

You could also check out [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), but that's written in Erlang.

Comment: MongoDB is hardly lightweight given that it's optimized to be the only process running on the PC, loads entire database in a memory-mapped file, tends to use up all the memory it can get and behaves haphazardly when limited.

I don't know enough about CouchDB, bud Erlang (the language/runtime) it runs on is interpreted garbage-collected runtime so it can't be that lightweight.

Comment: RethinkDB ( https://t.co/e4I6Q2MTQq ) seems to be lighter than MongoDB, but is probably a lot bigger than SQLite.